# Capybara code completion in RubyMine

Tags: cucumber, capybara, rubymine

Is there a way to get some help from *RubyMine*'s code completion when using *Capybara* in *Cucumber*'s step definitions? I'm new to *Capybara*, so not having to check the reference site all the time would be really helpful.

The best I can get at the moment is by explicitly calling `Session.new`, something like:

```
session = Capybara::Session.new(:rack_test, my_app)
```

This way `Ctrl+Space` after `session.` shows me methods from *Capybara::Session* (only) so at least I know it's somehow reachable. But that's not how I really use *Capybara* in my step definitions. I thought that helping the type inference engine by manually annotating `page` could do the trick, but I suppose all this *DSL* magic is too much to handle.

So basically, is it somehow possible to have

```
page.<Ctrl+Space>
```

pop up with all the exposed *DSL* methods? *[RubyMine API](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1161)* maybe? Or, as an alternative, some other way to bring the reference docs closer (I don't think *RubyMine* supports external docs in the IDE yet)?

Comment: It's almost impossible to create good code completion for dynamic languages such as ruby. Instead code completion you can create a set of useful code templates.

Comment: Most useful Capybara methods have short names. Why do you need code completion for them?

Comment: What rubymine version are you using. Rubymine 6 has improved suggestive text. but luacassus is right, it wouldnt be perfect.

Comment: At the time of writing, I think it might have been version 3.0 - not sure right now. I haven't been doing much in Ruby lately, so a lot might have changed since that time.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, found a solution.

I am using Cucumber with Capybara and I included all the matchers I wanted to code complete in `/features/support/spec/spec_helper.rb`. Cucumber auto-loads everything in this file. I bet there are other places you can include these statements if you aren't using cucumber.

```
# Needed for RubyMine code completion
include Capybara::Node::DocumentMatchers
include Capybara::Node::Matchers
include Capybara::SessionMatchers
include Capybara::RSpecMatchers
include Capybara::RSpecMatcherProxies
```

[image]

For your specific case:
`include Capybara::DSL`

Then

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of RubyMine 8.0.3 the answer is no, RubyMine does not complete Capybara methods following `page.` in Cucumber step definitions, at least not when Capybara is included in Cucumber via the cucumber-rails gem. [I don't see a feature request in the RubyMine issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY?q=capybara%20complet*); someone could add one if they like.

Note that cucumber-rails, at least, includes the Capybara DSL in the Cucumber world, so you don't need to type `page.` in front of Capybara methods. You can just call `visit`, `fill_in`, etc. as self methods. I wouldn't want unnecessary `page.` in my step definitions just for the sake of RubyMine completion.

Unfortunately, RubyMine also doesn't include Capybara methods in the list of names it completes when you invoke completion in a step definition before you type anything. It does include Capybara methods in the list of names it completes when you invoke completion twice (all names in all available code), but since that list is so long it's only helpful if you already know the method you want already, or at least a correct prefix.